# MariaDB missing records in replica

Tags: mysql, mariadb

My replica setup is all good (0 seconds behind master etc.). Most tables have accurate record counts but some have a thousand or more records missing.

Should I STOP SLAVE, delete the /var/lib/mysql directory on the replica, then run a fresh backup with MariaBackup on the primary, move it to the replica, then fire up START SLAVE on the replica again? Or is there a way without risking messing anything up on the primary?

Running MariaDB 10.1.30 on the primary and MariaDB 10.6.7 on the replica.

I broke replication a few times after it was running by updating a MySQL user on the master. I read you are supposed to delete the user and then re-create. All the errors I skipped were related to the queries for the updating of the MySQL user.

Comment: The replication of [alter user is a fixed bug (10.2.22+, 10.3.13+)](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-17753). I'd suggest a rebuild of /var/lib/mysql from a complete backup, ensure  the [mariabackup --prepare](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/setting-up-a-replica-with-mariabackup/) stage is done. Double check replication file/position/gtid too.

Answer (score 0):

I turns out that I was relying on the counts shown in PhpMyAdmin which are not exact record counts for larger InnoDB tables. For example I have a table that shows ~5,103,225 but when I click on the text it shows me the actual record count of 5,220,102 for that table. I should have known better when I saw the ~ character. Anyhow, my record counts were actually accurate all along. Doh!